# Flask url_for incorrectly links to static pages outside of templates

Tags: python, static, amazon-s3, flask, url-routing

I'm currently in the process of moving all of my static files to S3, as well as allowing some image uploads to my site. In general this is going fantastically. I got all of my existing css and js files up to S3 with no hassle, however I'm having some trouble with uploading images and saving them to S3.

Specifically this is how I'm handling file uploads within my view:

```
image_file = request.files["imageurl"]
if image_file and allowed_file(image_file.filename):
    fn = "products/%s" % secure_filename(image_title + "." + image_file.filename.split(".")[-1])
    image_file.save(url_for('static', filename=fn))
else:
    response = app.make_response(render_template(
        'admin/newImage.html',
        title=title,
        error="That Image file is invalid.")
    )
    return response
```

Which is all wrapping in a POST request handler. The problem here is that the `url_for('static')` fails to link to the correct path, and so I get an `IOError` anytime I try to save an image like this.

Normally I would assume I was just doing something silly with my directory structure, but the same pattern of `url_for` works perfectly for files in my static directory. Any ideas on how to remedy this? Here's my directory structure (trimmed down for viewing)

```
├── SpoolEngine
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── _forms.html
│   │   ├── posts
│   │   │   ├── complete.html
│   │   └── super_user
│   │       ├── base.html
│   ├── users.py
│   └── views.py
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── admin.css
    │   └── zebraTable.css
    ├── img
    │   └── subtle_grunge.png
    ├── js
    │   ├── compatibility.js
    │   ├── list.js
    │   ├── login.js
    │   └── profiler.js
    └── products
```

And for reference, url_for works perfectly within `/static/css` and links to the wrong url from `admin.py` Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`url_for` returns an url path. Not a filesystem path.

So you're trying to save your file at `/static/something` which, for the system, means a path starting from the root of your filesystem, not your application path.

You can create the `static` path for your file with something like this

```
static_path_to_save = os.path.join([app.root_path, '/static', fn])
```

Just a side note, when dealing with uploads, remember to sanityze all the paths and to double check the destination. Best practices applies, like stripping slashes if you use the `filename` provided by the user (best is if you generate the filename).

In your code I see also a problem if 2 users uploads a file with the same name, overwriting each other. But this is probably safe in your context.